# Tensorflow tf.concat

Tags: python, tensorflow

Sorry for asking a totally elementary question, but I'm trying to use the `tf.concat()` function. Just to get going, I try to run the example code on their site: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining

```
t1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
t2 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
tf.concat(0, [t1, t2])
```

This should generate the output: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]`.

However, I get the error message, saying that

> "Shapes (2, 2, 3) and () are incompatible".

Comment: Apparently, the parameter order has been swapped, so tf.concat([t1, t2],0) seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
tf.concat([t1, t2], 0)

Comment: That should be a comment really.

Comment: Your answer can be helpful if you explain a bit your reasoning .. explain your answer, it's already a comment from OP.